# Set styled <ul> as title value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let me explain what I'm doing:
I'm going through some array of strings and each of those strings is added to a `<li>` element and a certain class to change its color.
All those `<li>` elements are appended to a `<ul>` element which then is set as the "`title`"-property value of a `<label>` element.

Makes sense? :D

Instead of having a nice list in my tooltip I get stuff like this:
(please ignore that there's no `<ul>` element, I already fixed that)
[image]
Here's an example of how such a label looks like (copied outerHTML straight out of Chrome):

```
<label data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" class="btn btn-default" title="<ul><li class=&quot;green&quot;>Tequila</li><li class=&quot;green&quot;>Gin</li></ul>">Angel<input type="radio" id="cocktails" name="cocktail" value="angel"></label>
```

I thought `data-html="true"` solves this problem, but it doesn't in my case.

At the bottom at `.prop("title", tooltipElement.html())` I'm setting the title.
I don't know what the problem is, I tried so many things by now...
I feel it's some problem with `'` or `"`...but I have no idea how to fix it now.

Any idea how to do this the nicest way?
My code:

```
var tooltipElement = $("<ul></ul>");
        for (var u = 1; u < nameAndBottlesArr.length; u++)
        {
            var bottleAndBool = nameAndBottlesArr[u].split('=');
            var bottleName = bottleAndBool[0];
            var bottleBool = bottleAndBool[1];
            var colorClass = (bottleBool === '1') ? 'green' : 'red';
            var listEntry = $("<li></li>").addClass(colorClass).text(bottleName);
            tooltipElement.append(listEntry);
        }

        var cocktailName = nameAndBottlesArr[0];
        var alreadyListed = $('.btn-group').find('[value="' + cocktailName + '"]')[0];

        //Append Radiobutton for each Cocktail, disable unavailable cocktail-radios
        if (!alreadyListed) {
            var $radio = $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'radio',
                id: 'cocktails',
                name: 'cocktail',
                value: cocktailName
            });

            var $label = $('<label data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom"></label>')
                    .addClass("btn btn-default")
                    .prop("title", tooltipElement.html())
                    .text(cocktailName.replace(/\w\S*/g, capitalize));

            if (!sortedCocktails[i].availability) {
                $label.addClass("disabled");
            }
            $label.append($radio);
            $(".btn-group").append($label);
        }
```

Comment: Title attributes cannot be HTML, they're just text.

Comment: They can if you set the html data attribute to true.

Comment: But I had them styled successfully before, so there must be a way somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use HTML in a (native) tooltip. Instead you may want to make the list in pure Unicode using the bullet symbol "•" and a newline `&#10;`, like:

```
<label title="• line 1&#10;• line 2">
```

If you need anything more, you have to consider displaying tooltips on your own instead of depending on the browser, e.g. with Bootstrap Tooltips (in case you only need to style them):

https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Or with some more sophisticated tooltip library like Overlib if you need full HTML inside.

Comment: because of your answer, I found out what was missing :D - since I was using Bootstrap Tooltips I needed to activate them with `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` which I placed at a wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.prop("title"...)`, use `.attr("title"...`.

Comment: it didn't change anything ;(

Comment: Can you do a  `console.log(tooltipElement.html())` to see what's in it?